# Find $f(x)$ given $f(0), f(1)$ and $f[x1,x2,x3]$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I need to find f(x) given

> $f(0) = 0$,  $f(1) = 2$, and the divided difference $f[x_1,x_2,x_3] = 1$ for any three points $x_1, x_2, x_3$

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of
divided differences,
$f[x_0, x_1, x_2]
=\frac{f(x_0)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)}
+\frac{f(x_1)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}
+\frac{f(x_2)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}
$.

Putting
$x_0 = 0$, $x_1 = 1$,
 $x_2 = x$,
$f(0)=1$ and $f(1) = 2$,

$\begin{array}\\
1
&=f[0, 1, x]\\
&=\frac{f(0)}{(0-1)(0-x)}
+\frac{f(1)}{(1-0)(1-x)}
+\frac{f(x)}{(x-0)(x-1)}\\
&=\frac{0}{x}
+\frac{2}{(1-0)(1-x)}
+\frac{f(x)}{x(x-1)}\\
&=\frac{2}{(1-x)}
+\frac{f(x)}{x(x-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f(x)
=x(x-1)+2x
=x^2+x
$.